# The error about “contain method not supported”

Tags: dolphindb

I run the script below:

```py
store_code = ["AH0001","AH0003","AH0004","AH0005"]
typestr(store_code)
temp_store_tbl = table(store_code)

select * from shared_skx_tt6 where store_code in (exec * from temp_store_tbl)
select * from shared_skx_tt6 where store_code in (store_code)
```

An error appears:

```py
Contain method not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, the variable name and the field name cannot be the same, so the variable store_code needs to be renamed.

The script should be modified:

```py
store_code1 = ["AH0001","AH0003","AH0004","AH0005"]
typestr(store_code)
temp_store_tbl = table(store_code)

select * from shared_skx_tt6 where store_code in (exec * from temp_store_tbl)
select * from shared_skx_tt6 where store_code in (store_code1)
```